Question about OLS estimator (BLUE proof)
We know that the OLS estimator of $\beta$ is the unique BLUE.
The proof goes as follows. Consider the general linear estimator
$$\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_\mathbf{A} 
= \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_\text{OLS} + \mathbf{A} \mathbf{Y}
= \bigl[(\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T} + \mathbf{A}\bigr] \mathbf{Y}$$
The bias of $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_\mathbf{A}$ is $$\begin{align}\mathbb{E}\bigl[\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_\mathbf{A}-\beta\,\vert \mathbf{x}\bigr]&=
\mathbb{E}\bigl[\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_\mathbf{A}-\beta\,\vert \mathbf{x}\bigr] \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}\bigl[\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_\text{OLS} + \mathbf{A} \mathbf{Y} - \boldsymbol{\beta}\bigr\vert \mathbf{x}] \\[6pt]
&= \boldsymbol{\beta} + \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} \boldsymbol{\beta} - \boldsymbol{\beta} \\[6pt]
&= \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} \boldsymbol{\beta}, \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$ Hence the requirement of unbiasedness for $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_\mathbf{A}$ is
$$\mathbf{Ax}\beta=0$$
Now the proof says that we can assume that $\mathbf{Ax}=0$ and goes from here. Anyway, the rest of the proof is clear to me.
It's not clear to me why here $\mathbf{Ax}\beta=0\implies \mathbf{Ax}=0$.
I'd just say that $\mathbf{Ax}\beta=0\implies \mathbf{x}\beta\in\mathrm{Ker}(\mathbf{A})$, which is a weaker condition.
In other words, for $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_\mathbf{A}$ to be unbiased, why do we ask the Ker of $\mathbf{A}$ to contain the whole subspace $\mathrm{span}(\mathbf{x}_1,\dots,\mathbf{x}_K)$ (of dim K) rather than just the subspace $\mathrm{span}(\mathbf{x}\beta)$ (of dim 1)?
One possible answer to this point is that, for some reason, the condition $\mathbf{Ax}\beta=0$ is required to hold for all $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^K$. But I don't see why we should assume this condition for all $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^K$, as $\beta$ here is an unknown constant factor which depends on the specific regression problem.
What's wrong with this argument? Any help about this would be really appreciated.

In any case, you should cite the source of the proof and mention further the structure and approach the proof takes for better context.

$\hat{\beta}$ is not unbiased if it's only unbiased for some values of $\beta$.   Note that we are constructing a general proof that applies to all possible (subject to the usual conditions, e.g., restrictions on the errors) regression problems, not proving unbiasedness for a specific regression problem or some finite set of regression problems that have been observed in practice.

@User1865345 - thanks!  I'll do that!

Note that we are constructing a general proof that applies to all possible regression problems (subject to the usual conditions, e.g., homoskedasticity of the errors) , not proving unbiasedness for a specific regression problem or some finite set of regression problems that have been observed in practice. Consequently, $\hat{\beta}$ is not unbiased if it's only unbiased for some values of $\beta$, $x$, and $y$.
Given this, as you have realized, $Ax\beta = 0$ does indeed imply that $Ax = 0$.

Ok, now I got it! Thanks man. I missed the "forall part". We have an inference problem about some parameter $\theta$ lying in some parameter space $\Theta$. Then an estimator $\hat{\tau}$ of $\tau(\theta)$ is unbiased if the condition $\mathbb{E}[\hat{\tau}] = \tau(\theta)$ holds for all $\theta\in\Theta$. Right?

Also, in order to enhance the fact that the distribution of $\hat{\tau}$ depends on $\theta$, one can formulate the condition using the subscript as follows $\mathbb{E}_\theta[\tau]=\tau(\theta)$ for all $\theta\in\Theta$. Anyway thank you man. I was stuck, but now I get it!

Great!  That's what we're here for!
